# Variable name to strings, R

Tags: r

I have a question about convert variable name into strings to work as a x-axis name.

I tried to apply the deparse(substitute(input)), but unfortunately, it doesn't work well when I called this function within another function.

```r
plot_CI <- function(input){

  nm <- deparse(substitute(input))
  if (substring(nm,1,1) == 'u') {
    prior <- 'uniform'
  } else if ((substring(nm,1,1) == 'l')) {
    prior <- 'logit_Normal'
  } else {
    prior <- paste(strsplit(nm,"_")[[1]][1:2],collapse="_")
  }

  plot <- ggplot(temp_data, aes(x = x, y = mean)) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = high, ymin = low)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = true_value, col = 'blue') +
    labs(x=prior, y='value')
  return(plot)
}

sen_plot <- function(variable){
  # variable <- deparse(substitute(var))
  file_name <- paste0('C:/Users/Qiangsuper/Dropbox/Papers/1/plot/sensitivity_', variable, '.png')
  png(filename = file_name, width = 1000, height = 400)
  p1 <- plot_CI(eval(parse(text = paste0('uniform_', variable))))
  p2 <- plot_CI(eval(parse(text = paste0('logitN_', variable))))
  multiplot(p1,p2,cols=2)
  dev.off()
}

for (i in c("beta_1", "beta_2", "beta_3", "phi", "p", "delta")) {
  sen_plot(i)
}
```

I expect 'uniform' as X-axis name, however, I only received eval(parse(text = paste0('Uniform_', variable))). 
[image]
Thank you very much for your help.

- ***UPDATE ABOUT QUESTION:***

I think I should  make the question more concise. Here is an easily-understood scenario.

uniform_beta_1 is a data frame or data table, which stores the my results. I try to develop an automatic plotting algorithm which will automatically identify which prior distribution I applied and name the X-axis with this prior distribution. For uniform_beta_1, the prior distribution is uniform, then the X-axis's name will be uniform. Here is what I try to do:

```r
input <- uniform_beta_1
nm <- deparse(substitute(input))
```

Then apply the substring command to judge the prior distribution. However, in this case, nm will return 'input' rather than 'uniform_beta_1'. I am wondering if there is any way I can return 'uniform_beta_1'.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do?! Otherwise, take a look at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Did you try `colnames()` or `names()` ?

Comment: Thanks, @NelsonGon. I update my question and hopefully it is easier to understand now.

Comment: Thanks, @ANG. I would like to obtain the name of what this variable stands for. I express more detail in the updated question.

Answer (score -1):

The final solution for my question is that I create a list at very beginning and store all these strings into this list to avoid the transformation in the function.